# ClosureScript & NodeJS: Error: No *print-fn* fn set for evaluation environment

Tags: node.js, clojure, clojurescript

I have followed the "hello world!" examples for NodeJS on both these guides

- https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Quick-Start#running-clojurescript-on-nodejs
- http://mmcgrana.github.io/2011/09/clojurescript-nodejs.html

and for each I get this error

```
Error: No *print-fn* fn set for evaluation environment
```

Have I missed a step? This seems like a fairly basic problem ... does anyone know where print-fn is set?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can say

```
(enable-console-print!)
```

to print using `console.log`.

Under the hood, `enable-console-print!` sets `*print-newline*` and `*print-fn*`. Here's [the source](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/r2156/src/cljs/cljs/core.cljs#L49) as of r2156.

Comment: wow, brilliant, thanks michal... hours of banging my head against a wall there!!

Comment: This solution didn't work in my case. Rewriting the code to `(.log js/console "my string ...")` did the trick, however. I am assuming that because both Clojurescript and Node.js are relatively new technologies, we can expect a lot of versioning compatibility issues.